# How do I find per app records of network data usage in OS X and/or Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

My laptop used up 1.4 GB from my mobile data in 30 minutes, which is quite unusual. When I opened the Network tab in Activity Monitor, the per app tracking just started, but the total Data received was at 6 GB. Is there a record of the data usage per app?

Activity Monitor Screenshot:

[image]

I have a suspicion that this is from Chrome. If it is, is there a record of per tab/domain data transfer in Chrome?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  I just had 1.3gb of tethering burned and my Activity Monitor shows the usage like yours, but none of my apps show anything close to the 1.3gb used (have had the Activity Monitor open for _hours_ now).  The most is pgAdmin 155mb in, and node 24mb out, and most of the pgAdmin is local traffic only!    Quite concerning. @o@

Answer (score 1):

If you like it easy and with a Graphical User Interface and Money isn't a Point, i would recommend you to take a look at LittleSnitch https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/ mainly it is a better Firewall for OS X but you can also use it to Monitor which Application is using how much of your Traffic.

Or if Money is a Point and you can life with a Command Line Interface Application, then take a look at nettop https://www.cnet.com/news/use-nettop-command-to-check-per-application-network-activity-in-os-x/

Comment: Thanks. Would you know if history of per app traffic stored somewhere in the Mac? I've already installed Little Snitch for ongoing monitoring, but I'm hoping to understand what happened in those 30 minutes with 1.4GB.

Comment: i don't know any Programm witch can do this backwards - there are some tools that can go backwards but only til the time they got installed and are configured to go back to this point - you could try to have a look at the Console App  maybe the Logfiles go back till the Time/Date it happend

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this information would be on the line of the process you are trying to monitor. For example you are looking for the data usage of Chrome so look for Chrome on the left, and under the "Rcvd Bytes" header is the amount of data used by the application since Activity Monitor was opened.

Comment: Thanks. Any way to look at history? The number only shows the number after I opened the Network tab.

Comment: Unfortunately this can't be done without a Chrome extension. You could download one like DataSaver, but it would only show the usage since the extension was installed.

Answer (score 0):

- The (paying) app [TripMode](https://tripmode.ch) does what you want: **monitor** and
  **throttle** *app-specific* internet usage. It also allows to **block** *specific apps* from accessing the internet, in order to keep mobile
  data usage within limits:  [Tripmode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PenYE.png)
- For *global* **monitoring** and **throttling** only, [Bandwith+](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/bandwidth/id490461369?mt=12) is
  a free tool to monitor and throttle *global* aggregate internet usage:
  [Bandwith+ screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfZHs.png)
- For **blocking** *app-specific* internet usage, the free tool [Lulu](https://objective-see.com/products/lulu.html) can help you with that:
  [Lulu screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKLLj.png)